# type ip_address() undefined type ip_port() undefined

Tags: erlang

I am trying to build a piece of Erlang code on Ubuntu 14.04. I got the following error. It seems to be something wrong with the header file. I can not figure it out

type ip_address() undefined
type ip_port() undefined

Comment: you need to give more details if you want to get some help: describe completely your use case, provide the code you are using, the error report...

Comment: I am trying to compile a piece of code from github. Here is the link. https://github.com/Lyoko-Jeremie/erlkad.git     When I used make to coompile it, it gave me the following errors. kad_api.erl:185: type ip_address() undefined
kad_api.erl:186: type ip_port() undefined

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking at is quite old, and includes `kernel/include/inet.hrl`. This file [*used to*](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/84adefa331c4159d432d22840663c38f155cd4c1/lib/kernel/include/inet.hrl) define the `ip_address()` and `ip_port()` types, but those are now instead [exported](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/91b3a08c6f4afcf958171f1815347c8a5806fa97/lib/kernel/src/inet.erl#L77) from the `inet` module.

Just replace `ip_address()` with `inet:ip_address()`, and `ip_port()` with `inet:ip_port()`.

Though do note that there may have been other breaking changes in Erlang since that code was published.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code uses non-standard types. You can find all standard (built-in) types [in the official documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html).